# How to open the push notification in the WebView component of my app?

Tags: android, webview, app-inventor

Using OneSignal Push Notification system, I send different links as notifications to my app users. But when a user clicks on the notification, it opens the "Complete action using.." app list.

Is it possible to open those links inside a WebView component of my app? I'm using MIT app inventor. (The action would be like when someone clicks a notification from Facebook, it shows the content inside the Facebook app.)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get this working in App Inventor, you might want to try Thunkable, which is based on App Inventor but adds additional functionality, such as One Signal based Push Notifications.  Take a look at https://docs.thunkable.com/android/components/push-notifications.html

Hope this helps.

-Mark

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have implemented the Push Notification. I was asking how I can open the link of the notification that I send in the WebView component of my app.